# how to moving bitmap one by one

Tags: android

this is my full code,,,,

anyone can help me,,,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(new Panel(this));

    }
}


class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


         private Bitmap[] mBitmap;
        private ViewThread mThread;
        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
             mBitmap = new Bitmap[4];
                mBitmap[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.x);
                mBitmap[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.x);
                mBitmap[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.x);
                mBitmap[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.x);

            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            mThread = new ViewThread(this);
        }

        public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap[0], 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap[1], 45, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap[2], 90, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap[3], 135, 0, null);


        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
                mThread = new ViewThread(this);
                mThread.setRunning(true);
                mThread.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mThread.isAlive()) {
                mThread.setRunning(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap[0].getWidth() / 2;
            mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap[1].getWidth() / 2;
            mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap[2].getWidth() / 2;
            mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap[3].getWidth() / 2;

            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        }




class ViewThread extends Thread {
    private Panel mPanel;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    public ViewThread(Panel panel) {
        mPanel = panel;
        mHolder = mPanel.getHolder();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        mRun = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
            while (mRun) {
                canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mPanel.doDraw(canvas);
                    mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
    }

}
```

how to moving bitmap to right and left one by one my bitmap

if bitmap moving then bitmap adjoining

whats wrong in my code?

how to solve this my code?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

To move the object on the surface you will have to change the position of the object at regular time interval.

For getting started with 2D Game developement you can refer below links.

http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html

In this link there is also example code available so download and run it in your PC and check the code.